# C# subtype casted to super type but still want the subtype method called

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

```
class A
{
    public int SomeMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override int SomeMethod()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}

class DrivingClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B classB = new B();
        A classA = (A)classB;
        Assert.IsEqual(3, classA.SomeMethod()); 

    }
}
```

This fails of course expecting 3 but actual is 1.  Is there a way (without typecasting it back to B) for classA.SomeMethod() to call the overridden version since it started out as B(although I assume this knowledge is lost once casted).

UPDATE:
Class A is already written and for all intents and purposes can not be edited.  I can only control class B. Knowing the class B will be casted to type A, I simply want my implementation to be used when SomeMethod() is called on my typecasted B.

Comment: The posted code doesn't compile.  Did you mean class A's method to be `virtual`?

Comment: please, at least make some effort to compile your sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SomeMethod` needs to be declared as **virtual** in A in order to successfully **override** it in B.

```
 public virtual int SomeMethod() // in A
 public override int SomeMethod() // in B
```

With this properly in place

```
 A a = new B();
 int value = a.SomeMethod(); 
 Debug.Assert(value == 3); // succeeds
```

If you *instead* have

```
 public int SomeMethod() // in A
 public new int SomeMethod() // in B, or just 
 public int SomeMethod() // in B
```

Then the above assertion fails. The method in B hides the base method, but only via the B reference. When operating under the reference of A, you get the base behaviors.

```
 A a = new B();
 int value = a.SomeMethod(); // gets 1 from A, not 3 from B
```

---

> UPDATE: Class A is already written and for all intents and purposes can not be edited. I can only control class B. Knowing the class B will be casted to type A, I simply want my implementation to be used when SomeMethod() is called on my typecasted B.

Methods are not virtual by default in C#. If the authors of `A` did not design it with extensibility in mind (at least, as far as overriding `SomeMethod`), you will not be able to replace or override that behavior with `B` when it is being treated as `A`. However, *if* you are in a position to control the *casting*, or rather the dependency of the code, you can perhaps invert it so that `A` actually adheres to the contract of `B`, not the other way around. Consider the *Adapter Pattern*, for example.

```
interface IB
{
    int SomeMethod();
}

class B : IB
{
    public int SomeMethod() { return 3; }
}

class ABAdapter : IB
{
    private A a; 
    public ABAdapter(A a) { this.a = a; }
    public int SomeMethod() { return a.SomeMethod(); } 
}
```

In this example, you've used the adapter to pattern to make `A` actually fulfill the contract of `B`, via the `IB` interface. So code that might once have depended upon `A` or `B` can now depend upon `IB`. The ABAdapter simply delegates to the A implementation.

```
public void DoSomething(IB ib) // given 

A a = new A();
DoSomething(new ABAdapter(a)); // invoke with A
DoSomething(new B()); // invoke with B
```

Comment: Sorry, I left a most important constraint that I don't control class A, and cannot add virtual to the already defined method in A.  I have complete control over B however, and B is what's being instantiated and later casted to A. Does this make the initial question impossible?

Comment: Yes. The authors of A did not design it with extensibility in mind (at least, not as far as overriding this particular method), and you are not able to override or replace their implementation *except* only via your B reference. Methods are not virtual by default in C#, unlike in (say) Java.

Comment: @OnResolve, is the casting to A something you *can* control or is that similarly out of your hands?

Comment: I control the cast, does this give the problem an advantage?

Comment: It might. You can wrap the A, so that code does not actually depend upon A and you don't cast to A. One such applicable pattern *might* be the Adapter Pattern, and I've provided an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `SomeMethod` to be virtual in `A`, so this clearly isn't your real code (as otherwise `B` can't override it) but when you make that change, it *will* return 3. If it didn't, polymorphism would be completely broken.

Now, the other change we could make to the code you've posted is in B. If you use:

```
public new int SomeMethod()
{
    return 3;
}
```

*Then* your assertion would fail - because it would be calling `A.SomeMethod()` which is *shadowed* or *hidden* by `B.SomeMethod()`, not overridden. Basically, if you want polymorphic behaviour, you need to use `override`, and it has to be on a virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading up on the topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
In the article it shows these code examples:

```
class A
{
   public void F() { Console.WriteLine("A.F"); }
   public virtual void G() { Console.WriteLine("A.G"); }
}
class B: A
{
   new public void F() { Console.WriteLine("B.F"); }
   public override void G() { Console.WriteLine("B.G"); }
}
class Test
{
   static void Main() {
      B b = new B();
      A a = b;
      a.F(); //prints A.F
      b.F(); //prints B.F
      a.G(); //prints B.G (due to virtual method override)
      b.G(); //prints B.G
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your edit stating that you cannot redefine class `A`, I'm afraid you're more or less out of luck.

It's possible to derive `B` from `A`, and then declare `new int SomeMethod()`, but you won't be able to call that method with an `A` reference.  You could use a run-time type check:

```
int CallSomeMethod(A obj)
{
    var b = obj as B;
    return b == null ? obj.SomeMethod() : b.SomeMethod();
}
```